# Why does Kotlin allow variable declarations with the same name as a parameter inside a method?

Tags: kotlin

Why does Kotlin allow variable declarations with the same name as a parameter inside a method? Then also, is there any way to access the 'hidden' parameter?

For example:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val args = Any()
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is called **shadowing** and it is useful for decoupling your code from other parts of the system. It is possible because names are bound to the current scope.

Consider this:

You subclass a class `Foo` from someone else, let's say an API. In your code you introduce a variable `bar`. The author of `Foo` also updates his code and also adds a variable `bar`. Without the local scope, you would get a conflict.

By the way, this is also possible in other JVM bases languages including Java and commonly used within constructors or setters:

```
public TestClass(int value, String test) {
    this.value = value;
    this.test = test;
}

public void setFoo(String foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
}
```

Shadowing does not only apply to parameters, other things can be shadowed too: fields, methods and even classes.

Most IDEs will warn you about shadowing as it can be confusing.

**Recommendation for our own code:**

try to avoid shadowing for two reasons:

- your code becomes hard to read as two different things have the same name, which leads to confusion.
- once shadowed, you can no longer access the original variable within a scope.

Comment: The few cases where shadowing is useful is not worth the dangers of using it.  I wish they simply didn't allow it in kotlin.  If someone changes a function with a conflicting parameter, the least you can do is fix the conflicts, which should be underlined in red as an `error`.

Answer (score 13):

Kotlin does issue a warning about name shadowing which you can suppress with:

```
@Suppress("NAME_SHADOWING")
val args = Any()
```

Allowing for such shadowing may be handy in some cases e.g. throwing a custom exception after parameter validation:

```
fun sample(name: String?) {
    @Suppress("NAME_SHADOWING")
    val name = name ?: throw CustomArgumentRequiredException()
    println(name.length)
}
```

It is unfortunately not possible to access the shadowed variable.

It is also not possible to turn [a warning into an error](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-18783) at the moment.

Comment: I use this kind of shadowing to normalize the parameter value as well (such as `string.trim().toLowerCase()`). I specifically _want_ the original parameter to disappear from the rest of the scope.

Comment: You can also remove shadowing by running code in [with blocks](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Something also to note and if it isn't already realized or if anyone else new comes along. In kotlin you don't have access to the params if they are not prefixed with var/val until you add them as properties. So if a basic class was defined as this:

```
class Person(name: String, age: Int){

}
```

you can't use name or age until they are in scope; however it is unnecessary to shadow
with exceptions of desired reasons as miensol pointed out, but for the sake of being basic.

```
class Person(name: String, age: Int){
     var name = name 
     var age = age
}
```

do these in the constructor

```
class Person(var name: String, private var age: Int){           
}
```

you also will of course then have access based on the signature you gave on the object created.