# How to call global variable within if statement in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, scope, global-variables, local-variables

a very simple question regarding Kotlin. What if a global variable (in function context) has the same name as a local variable declared within if statement.
As you can see there are two msg variables, how to call outsider msg within if statement.

```
fun main() {

    var point = 100

    var msg = "Kotlin"

    if(point >= 50) {

        var msg = "Java"

        // print msg Java
        println(msg)

        // How to print msg Kotlin instead of Java
        println(msg)

    }
}
```

Comment: That's not a global variable, that's just another local variable with a wider scope. The second `msg` is said to "shadow" the first, meaning the first cannot be accessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to not be possible:

[Why kotlin allows to declare variable with the same name as parameter inside the method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49680040/why-kotlin-allows-to-declare-variable-with-the-same-name-as-parameter-inside-the)

Just avoid shadowing, it's confusing anyway. Your IDE will probably tell you though.