# How does variable with declaration 'val' work inside for loop in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

```
fun main() {
    val i = 1
    for (i in 1..10)
        println(i)
}
```

This prints numbers from 1 to 10 but the variable `i` is declared as `val`. Is this valid/possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer `i` (`val i = 1`) is just being shadowed by the inner loop. The variables are different, so in answer to your question: yes it is possible and valid. You can verify this by printing after the loop:

```
val i = 1
for (i in 1..10) print(i)

println()
print(i)
```

which outputs:

```
12345678910
1
```

There's quite a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49688168/10082297) which talks about why shadowing is a *feature* and why it can be useful.